# How to find the optimal grid placement for least distance between nodes of a network?

Tags: algorithm, networking, grid, nearest-neighbor

If I wanted to display the nodes of a network on a 2D grid, but also I wanted to ensure the least amount of manhattan distance between any two directly connected nodes (where there is a maximum of one node per cell), what is the algorithm to do this?

To clarify, let me provide an elementary example:

A network has the following topology:
A -> B -> C

One solution of the grid placement would simply be to list the 3 items next to each other:

`| A | B | C |`

The distance between any two connecting nodes is 1 cell.

Suppose another network has the following topology:
A -> B -> C -> D -> A

One solution of the place for this network would be:

`| A | B |
| D | C |`

The distance between A and B, B and C, C and D, and D and A are each 1 cell. B and D, and A and C are not directly connected, therefore their distances do not factor into the problem.

The most optimal arrangement would be the one that provides the lowest sum distance between all directly connected nodes.

Now, how would one do this for an arbitrary network? Any help would certainly be appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you be more precise about the optimality function? For example, which is preferable for a graph with 10001 connections: A grid in which the distance between all but two of the connected nodes is 1, but the distance between the last connected pair is 1000 (distance sum = 11000, squared distance sum = 1010000), or a grid in which the distance between all of the connected nodes is 2 (distance sum = 20000, squared distance sum = 40000)?

Comment: Mshnik, I should mention that the distance between nodes that are not directly connected doesn't factor in the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Looking for the lowest sum should return the same answer as looking for the lowest average (since every answer to a given problem has the same size), so you may want to go with that instead.

Answer (score 0):

A divide and conquer approach may bear some fruit. Consider the following algorithm:

if the cardinality of the graph is less than 10:

1) Create a 3x3 grid. Place this node of this piece of the graph on the grid in such a way that minimizes distance.

2) Return the 3x3 grid

else

1) Split the graph into two sets of nodes, recurse on each. Each recursion returns a graph of the optimal way to lay out that subset of the graph as a grid. Ideally you would find the minimum bisection for this split, but [that problem is NP-hard](http://tracer.lcc.uma.es/problems/bisect/bisect.htm), so perhaps an approximation?

2) Union the two subgraphs by creating a single grid with the returns of the two recursive calls next to one another. You can rotate the return of a recursive call by 90 degrees without changing it's distance sum, so there are 16 (4 orientations per) ways to union two grids. Large, but thankfully constant. Return the unioned grid that minimizes the total distance.

Clearly the factor that breaks this algorithm are the connections that span the subgrids. The rotation process only partially fixes this.

If you know your graph is planar, there's probably a way to do this optimally. Otherwise, you may be stuck with an approximation as your best solution, as for any given node with out degree > 4 you'll have to pick at least one neighbor to put at distance >= 2.

Another thing to consider is how to do the inner most step of putting <= 9 nodes on a 3x3 grid optimally. The problem is that there are probably many equally optimal ways to put the nodes on the grid in terms of the subgrid's cost, but you also want to make sure that nodes with related out-going edges (edges going out of this sub problem) are on the same side of the grid.